# Can't output to stdout twice in nasm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm learning basic NASM x86 assembly, and I'm having issues printing to `stdout` twice in the same binary. My code is:

```
section .data
    pokelst:                dw  'Bulbasaur',0xa,'Charmander',0xa,'Squirtle',0
    pokelstLen:             equ $-pokelst
    endl:                   db      '\n'
    smiley:                 db  '\u23a',0xa
    smileyLen:              equ $-smiley

section .text
    global _start
    _start:
            mov ebx,1
            mov ecx,smiley
            mov eax,4
            mov edx,smileyLen
            int 80h
            int 80h
            mov eax,1       ;syscall code 1 is exit
            mov ebx,0       ;ebx contains exit code (canonically, 0 means no errors)
            int 80h         ;int 80h=syscall
```

The output was:

```
\u23a
 ocket8888@ParanoidLinux  ~ 
```

Ignoring the fact that it's not resolving uni-code, it seems to me that if I use `int 80h` twice, it should print twice. But, it very clearly is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int 80h` returns length written in `eax`, so it's no longer 4/sys_write for your second `int 80h`

Comment: Relevant code should be included in your question, not linked to.

Comment: I've had questions deleted before for posting code instead of linking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the `RETURN` section or `write(2)`...

> On  success,  the  number  of bytes written is returned (zero
>   indicates nothing was written).  On error, -1  is  returned,  and 
>   errno  is  set appropriately.

After this call finishes, a value is returned to `EAX`. That means, when you try to run the interrupt again, you are going to be running a different interrupt.